# Update statement error during command execution

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(strMySqlConnectionString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "UPDATE user" & "SET FirstName = @FirstName" & "From user" & "WHERE Username = @Username;"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text '// You missed this line
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", editFirsName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", editusername.Text)


            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
                MsgBox("User Was Update succesfully")
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

    If iReturn = False Then
    End If
```

I am getting the following error from the code above:

> Fatal Error Encountered during command execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL update syntax appears incorrect.

**Change:**

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE user" & "SET FirstName = @FirstName" & "From user" & "WHERE Username = @Username;"
```

**To**

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE user SET FirstName = @FirstName WHERE Username = @Username;"
```

Comment: im still getting the Fatal Error Encountered during command execution.

Comment: 1. Is this valid SQL for your database in question? 2. Is your `strMySqlConnectionString` connection string in the following format `strMySqlConnectionString = "Server=**.**.**.**;Port=3306;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;"`

Comment: yes its valid and, Dim strMySqlConnectionString As String = "SERVER=localhost;" & "DATABASE=Photomod;" & "UID=root;" & "PASSWORD="


Im having problem now with the execution:  *Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
                MsgBox("User Was Update succesfully")
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try*